# Telling Azure SQL Database to pull data from Excel Online Document?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, azure-sql-database, excel-online

Good morning! I've found *TONS* of articles, questions, and guides on how to import data from local excel documents to Azure SQL databases, or how to pull *from* an Azure database to Excel, but *nothing* about how I could use SQL to query an excel online document (which would be hosted on SharePoint).
I'm fairly new in my learning - I'd be setting this up via a query in SQL written/executed via Azure Data Studio. The excel file is one that I'd be creating, and hosting via our company's SharePoint system. The Azure SQL database will also be one that I'm constructing myself, which is in progress. I've tried to find walkthroughs, scripts, explanations, *something*. But it's totally silent. Granted, that could be an indicator that it can't be done, but I figured I'd ask here. Overall, I'm just trying to figure out what *is* possible, so I can come up with a decent range of simple, easy-to-use means of data input for my team, or, in this case, to capture some of the ways they're tracking their work.
Not sure if this is sufficient detail, please feel free to ask any follow-up questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Studio is a tool to work with SQL databases, most notably MS SQL. Though you can connect to some other types as well.

Therefore, in order to use Data Studio to query your data, it needs to be in a SQL database. To accomplish that, you need to setup a process to load the data from your Excel document into a table in you database and run that process on a regular basis to update the table. You could look into Azure Data Factory to do that, though I don't see why you should bother to do that just to use Azure Data Studio, when you can browse the data in Excel, use PowerBI, Qlik or any other tool that can connect directly to Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am aware of the ADS detail - I've already created and queried/experimented with Azure SQL Databases *via* Azure Data Studio. I've heard of Data Factory, and though it is intriguing, I think it'd be something to look into later.
My question moreso is whether I *have* to go through an intermediary software like PowerBI, or if I can just query the file directly, and how. Any tips would be appreciated!